# Can a table be split into multiple entities based on a type column in entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Lets say I have a table Contacts:

```
ContactType
FirstName
LastName
CustomerId
Department
etc...
```

And ContactType is

```
Buyer
Sales
```

Can I use entity framework to split this into two different entities?
Is there a way to annotate the configuration builder to specify that my Buyer entity has ContactType=Buyer and my SalesRep entity has ContactType=SalesRep?

I've searched for a while, and I've seen ways to split a table horizontally so that I can split the columns into multiple entities, but I haven't found a way to split up different records from the same table into different entities.

Comment: This sounds exactly like EF [Table per Hieararchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) inheritance strategy. Create abstract `Contact` entity, create derived `Buyer` and `SalesRep` entities, configure (with fluent API) the `ContactType` column as discriminator (with the corresponding values) and EF will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you don't want to change your original database tables. You want to add functionality to your DbContext as if you had a DbSet and a DbSet

You want to do this using the configuration builder. Another approach would be to add functionality to your DbContext.

What functionality should be added depends on what you want with your Buyers and SalesReps. Do you only want to perform queries, or do you want to be able to change a Buyer which internally will change your Contacts table?

### Query only

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}

    public IQueryable<Buyer> Buyers
    {
        get
        {
             return this.Contacts.Select(contact => new Buyer()
             {
                  // fill all buyer properties:
                  Id = contact.Id,
                  FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                  ...
             };
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<SalesRep> SalesReps { ... similar to Buyers }
}
```

### Change values

If you also want to be able to change the `Buyers` and `SalesReps` you need to create a class that will give you full `IDbSet` functionality and add a Getter to you DbContext

(ignoring input parameter checks)

```
class DbSetBuyer : IDbSet<Buyer>
{
     public DbSetBuyer(MyDbContext dbContext)
     {
         this.owningContext = dbContext;
     }
     private readonly MyDbContext owningContext;

     public Buyer Add(Buyer buyer)
     {
          this.owningContext.Add(new Contact()
          {
               ContactType = ContactType.Buyer,
               FirstName = buyer.FirstName,
               ...
          }
     }
     public Buyer Remove (Buyer buyer)
     {
          Contact contactToRemove = this.owningContext.Contacts.Find(buyer.Id);
          if (contactToRemove != null
              this.owningContext.Contacts.Remove(contactToRemove);
     }
}
```

So for every IDbSet function you create something that will fetch / set / remove
the proper Contact from MyDbContext while converting your Buyers to Contacts
vice versa.

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(...) : DbContext(...)
    {
        this.Buyers = new DbSetBuyers(this);
        this.SalesReps = new DbSetSalesReps(this);
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
    public IDbSet<Buyer> Buyers {get; private set;}
    public IDbset<SalesRep> SalesReps {get; private set;}
}
```

Users of your DbContext won't see the difference between an original DbSet and your Buyers and SalesReps:

```
using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    var buyerToChange = myDbContext.Buyers
        .Where(buyer => ...)
        .Orderby(buyer => ...)
        .FirstOrDefault();
     if (buyerToChange != null)
     {
         buyerToChange.Department = ...;
     }
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting!  I might give this a try and get back to you on how that goes.  It does seem like more work than I was hoping, I was just hoping there was a way to configure this in fluent API.  My other approach was just going to be handling this on the backend by creating views and whatever else is required, but now that I think about it is is probably as much or more work...  thanks for the advise though I learned something new!

Comment: Apparently there was a reason that in your case TPH is used as inheritance design. The DbContext is supposed to represent your database. Not how you use your database. Therefore I would split between Buyers and SalesReps in your Repository pattern or unit-of-work. Not in your DbContext. But that is what you asked for